# Pad list in Python

Tags: python, list, padding

How can I pad a list when printed in python?

For example, I have the following list:

```
mylist = ['foo', 'bar']
```

I want to print this padded to four indices, with commas. I know I can do the following to get it as a comma and space separated list:

```
', '.join(mylist)
```

But how can I pad it to four indices with 'x's, so the output is like:

```
foo, bar, x, x
```

Comment: just in case: you should not use 'list' as a variable name

Comment: What result do you want if `mylist` contains five items?

Comment: @EthanFurman, good question, thankfully this situation should never occur with the code I'm using. I guess it should appear as `foo, bar, baz, qux, wibble`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
In [1]: l = ['foo', 'bar']

In [2]: ', '.join(l + ['x'] * (4 - len(l)))
Out[2]: 'foo, bar, x, x'
```

The `['x'] * (4 - len(l))` produces a list comprising the correct number of `'x'`entries needed for the padding.

**edit** There's been a question about what happens if `len(l) > 4`. In this case `['x'] * (4 - len(l))` [results in an empty list](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations), as expected.

Comment: What happens if len(l) is greater than 4?

Comment: @ovgolovin: It works as expected: multiplying a sequence by a negative number yields an empty sequence (in case you're wondering, this is documented behaviour -- I'll add a link in a moment).

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility using itertools:

```
import itertools as it

l = ['foo', 'bar']

', '.join(it.islice(it.chain(l, it.repeat('x')), 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `grouper()` recipe from [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
>>> L = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> ', '.join(next(izip_longest(*[iter(L)]*4, fillvalue='x')))
'foo, bar, x, x'
```

It probably belongs in the "don't try it at home" category.