# Edge pad both sides of a list in Python

Tags: python, list, padding

What is the best way to pad a Python `list` to a specific length by repeating the start element at the start and end element at the end?

For example, I have the following list of 5 elements:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

and I want to edge pad both sides of it so it has a new length of 10, producing

```
# either
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']

# or 
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e']
```

(When the target length minus the current length is an odd number, as in the example above, I don't mind which of the start and end elements is repeated once more than the other in order to correctly pad the list to the target length.)

*There are several other related questions on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438756/some-built-in-to-pad-a-list-in-python), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026131/padding-a-list-in-python-with-particular-value) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714287/pad-list-in-python), for example), but all of these concern zero padding (or similar) only one side. I am specifically asking about **edge padding both sides**.*

Answer (score 2):

I think your answer is fine, the only improvement I would make is to use `itertools` iterators for efficiency, if that is a consideration:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
final_len = 10

diff = final_len - len(my_list)
left = diff // 2
right = diff - left
result = list(chain(repeat(my_list[0], left), my_list, repeat(my_list[-1], right)))
```

Answer (score 2):

`divmod` gives both needed numbers at once, otherwise the same as landogardner ans

```
a, n = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 10

q, r = divmod(n - len(a), 2)

ap = [a[0]]*q + a + [a[-1]]*(q + r)

ap
Out[660]: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using simple list manipulations:

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
target_len = 10

diff = target_len - len(my_list)
left = diff // 2  # explicit integer division
right = diff - left
result = left*[my_list[0]] + my_list + right*[my_list[-1]]

print(result)
```

Which outputs:

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']
```

Using this method, if the target length minus the current length is an odd number, it is the end element which is repeated once more than the start element.